# House Party Protocol glitch?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

I finished the story and all, and done the bonus mission in Stark Tower named "House Party Protocol" got Stan Lee in Peril and True Believers, yet when I try to go in again for the Red Brick, it doesn't ask me if I want to do it in Free play mode or not, in which I cannot get the Red Brick. Any help on this? (I'm on the PC btw).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to go back to these Deadpool mini-missions in Free Play to earn the stuff you can only get when you can switch freely, do *not* re-enter the door you used the first time.

Instead, open the map and select the icon for the mission like you would if you were fast traveling or setting a waypoint.  Once you select it, you'll be given the Free Play option, but only if you've already completed it once.

(As a side note, this is also a good way to figure out if you've cleared a mission or Deadpool mission - only ones you've played to completion at least once will bring up the Free Play option.  Ones you haven't played will just bring up the waypoint selection option.)

Comment: Just a tip that you can select any available Deadpool mission on the map, and then can use L-R to move between the other missions to select.

Comment: @agent86 Thanks for that tip mate! :D